# Custom date validator in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, date, validation, user-registration

I have a problem ...
I have a user registration form .. in this form I have 3 fields that represent the day, month and year of birth. I like to have 3 fields distinct (3 menus). how can I create a validator that allows me to check if a valid date? (not accept dates like 30/02/2011)  I could do it in JavaScript (client side), but even if I wanted to have the validator as usual in model-vew-controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind validators to classes instead of properties.
I would do something like that:

```
//The Model
[DateValidator]
public class Date
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}

//The DataAnnotation
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class DateValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var date = value as Date;
        Debug.Assert(date != null);

        var dateString = date.Month + date.Day + date.Year;
        DateTime dateTime;
        var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
                                             out dateTime);
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

### Edit

DateTime.TryParseExact DOES check the validity of a DateTime (i.e. it will return false if you try to parse 30/02/2011).

Answer (score 0):

Create your model binder which will get those 3 fields from context and validate them altogether.

Comment: Could you kindly  post  a simple example of this?

Comment: There're tons of different approaches. One of them: http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/ExtendingTheModelBinderForEnhancedValidation

Comment: Another good one: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs